# hyperlink in DetailsView not generating correctly

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, detailsview

I'm trying to get a page to redirect to a particular Department based upon ID:  The Item Template is set up like this:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='~\Project.aspx?Project=<%# Eval("Project")%>' Text='<%# Eval("Project")%>'></asp:HyperLink>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```

This is what I end up with:

http://mydomain/Project.aspx?Project=%3C%# Eval("Project")%>

Answer (score 0):

This Will do the job:

> ```
>     <ItemTemplate>
>         <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" 
>             NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format(@"~\Project.aspx?Project={0}", Eval("Project")) %>'
>             Text='<%# Eval("Project") %>'></asp:HyperLink>
>     </ItemTemplate>
> ```